# Relating two tables with composite keys when one column is a derived value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two existing, highly normalized, tables (`Activity` and `Status`)

```
Create table Activity (
   id Number(10,0) not null,
   description varchar2(4000) not null,
   create_date date not null
);
Create table Status (
    table_name varchar2(20) not null,
    record_id number(10,0) not null,
    status_description varchar2(4000)
);
```

The `Status` table relates, in this case, to the `Activity` table by the following:

```
STATUS.TABLE_NAME = 'Activity' and STATUS.RECORD_ID = ACTIVITY.ID
```

It can relate to many other tables as well (besides ACTIVITY):

```
STATUS.TABLE_NAME = 'Scores' and STATUS.RECORD_ID = SCORE.ID
STATUS.TABLE_NAME = 'Submissions' and STATUS.RECORD_ID = submission.ID
STATUS.TABLE_NAME = 'Tickets' and STATUS.RECORD_ID = TICKET.ID
STATUS.TABLE_NAME = 'Profiles' and STATUS.RECORD_ID = Profile.ID


 - STATUS TABLE -
table_name   |   record_id  |  status_decription
-----------  | -----------  |  -----------
'Activity'   |       **12** | 'Finished'
'Profiles'   |          100 | 'Completed'
'Scores'     |          200 | 'Calculated'
'Tickets'    |         1000 | 'Paid'


 - ACTIVITY TABLE -
id           |   description  
-----------  | ------------- 
10           |  blah, blah
11           |  hey there..
**12**       |  order pizza 
13           |  pick up icecream
```

So given the previous example tables, there was an activity where an individual `"'Finished' ordering his pizza"`

I am trying to create this relationship with Hibernate, however I cannot seem to figure out the mapping between these two classes.

```
@Entity(name="status")
@Table(name="Status")
public class StatusDb {

    @Column(name="table_name")
    private String tableName;

    @Column(name="record_id")
    private String recordId;

    @Column(name="status_desc")
    private String description;

    // setters/getters
    // equals/hashCode
}

@Entity(name="actvity")
@Table(name="Activity")
public class ActivityDb {

    @Column(name="id")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    // setters/getters
    // equals/hashCode
}
```

How can I relate this `@OneToOne` mapping between the `Status` table and the `Activity`,`Profiles`,`Tickets`,`Workflow` tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me

```
@Entity(name="status")
@Table(name="Status")
public class StatusDb {

    @Column(name="table_name")
    private String tableName;

    @Column(name="record_id")
    private String recordId;

    @Column(name="status_desc")
    private String description;

    // setters/getters
    // equals/hashCode
}

@Entity(name="actvity")
@Table(name="Activity")
public class ActivityDb {

    @Column(name="id")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany
    @Where(value="table_name='Activity'")
    @JoinTable(name="STATUS", joinColumn=@JoinColumn(name="id"), 
                        reverseJoinColumn=@JoinColumn(name="record_id")
    private Set<StatusDb> status;  // Had to to make 1:M to use where clause

    // setters/getters
    // equals/hashCode
}
```

Comment: In order to use the @Where annotation, I had to wrap the `StatusDb` in a `Set`.  This allowed me to specify the where clause joined with the Status table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the ActivityDb is the 'parent' of the relationship.

I would map my entities as follows:

**StatusDb**

```
@Entity(name="status")
@Table(name="Status")
public class StatusDb {

    @Column(name="table_name")
    private String tableName;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="tableName = 'Activity'"),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn("record_id",                   
              referencedColumnName="id"))
    })
    private ActivityDb activityDb;

    @Id
    @Column(name="record_id")
    private String recordId;

    @Column(name="status_desc")
    private String description;

    // setters/getters
    // equals/hashCode
}
```

**ActivityDb**

```
@Entity(name="actvity")
@Table(name="Activity")
public class ActivityDb {

    @Column(name="id")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "activityDb")
    private StatusDb statusDb;
}
```

Now when the id is determined for the ActivityDb entity, upon commit of the transaction, the related StatusDb entity will automatically have the record_id populated with that ActivityDb's id.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  The only issue I am seeing is that `StatusDb` can/does relate to many other tables/entities, besides `ActivityDb`.  Is there a way to avoid having to put all the entities that it can relate to inside the Class?

Comment: Not sure exactly what is your intention but you do not need to map all the columns of a table, you can pick the ones that you want. Also if you a worried that those other dependnecies will be fetched during load of StatusDb, then mark them with FetchType.LAZY

Comment: My intention is to relate the `StatusDb` entity to many other entities based on the their table_name and record_id.  In your example, you've specifically related `StatusDb` to `ActivityDb` by putting a reference of "activityDb" in the `StatusDb` table.  Although this may work for the given example, I am trying to allow it to work for other relationships, beyond Activity.  I've updated my initial question, providing further examples of of what relationships we might see.

Comment: ok i get it now. Check out my updated answer with the use of JoinColumnFormula

Comment: I dont think that would work for the expanded question.  There's still an `ActivityDb` entity within the `StatusDb` entity.  So if I wanted to create a relationship between my 'ProfileDb' entity and the `StatusDb` entity, then I'd have to embed a profileDb instance...   Is there a way to make the relationship more generic?

Comment: YEs you would need to create separate instance fields for each of the relationships. What you are trying to achieve might be quite difficult to maintain if it is actually possible.. You would definately need to create some base parent class, mark it as @MappedSuperClass and then make all the other entities in question inherit from it.. But i have never done such a feat so my knowledge end here m8. And again, even if this can be pulle off, it would be a pain to maintain

Comment: I tried to implement what you suggested above, however I am getting "@Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property..."